# white spaces in download links python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download geographical data from this website:

http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/08/ES.SDGC.CP.atom_08.xml

which has dataset from multiple municipalities.

Here is the code i'm running to get the links with the `.zip`files:

```
import requests
import urllib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/08/ES.SDGC.CP.atom_08.xml'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

Then I get the dataset list thru:

```
for link in soup.find_all('link'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The problem comes with those links belonging to municipalities with names with more than one word, that means with white spaces on it, like this:

`code_mun = '08002'`

`nom_mun = 'AGUILAR DE SEGARRA'`

I can't retrieve the data with the following script:

```
download_url = 'http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/08/' + code_mun + '-' + nom_mun + '/A.ES.SDGC.CP.'+ code_mun + ".zip"`
out = my_path
urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url, my_path + '.zip')
```

The point is that if you copy/paste the link and run it into the web browser it works, it downloads the file, but not if you run script.

I've tried with `nom_mun.replace(' ', '%')` but it doesn't work as well.

Any help?

Comment: Try urlencoding the link - [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib` does the job, but you don't need it:

```
import urllib.parse

code_mun = '08002'
nom_mun = urllib.parse.quote('AGUILAR DE SEGARRA')
download_url = f"http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/08/{code_mun}-{nom_mun}/A.ES.SDGC.CP.{nom_mun}.zip"
```

Code below to download:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.catastro.minhap.es/INSPIRE/CadastralParcels/08/ES.SDGC.CP.atom_08.xml'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.select("entry link")
for link in links:
    href = link["href"]
    file_name = href.split('/')[-1]
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link["href"]).content)
```